# drawRect coordinates on Android

Tags: android, canvas, drawrect

Im trying to draw something using drawRect on Canvas and it drives me crazy.

Im using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
    android:layout_marginRight="0px"
    >
<ru.maaaah.client.android.GameView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my GameView code is:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(false);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), paint);
}
```

The problem is the rectangle lacks left side!

If I draw using Rect(1, 1, 100, 100) it appears as if top left Canvas corner is not (0, 0).

Im using Galaxy III running Android 4.3.

Please help, Im totally lost.

Comment: Stroke is *centered* on the shape. Since this is a width of 1, it is most likely outside your Rect boundaries.

Comment: I agree with @dharms.  Stroke draws on the outside of your provided Rect boundaries.  Also - you shouldn't create a new Paint everytime onDraw is called as this will result in lots of unnecessary object creation and slow down your drawing.  Create it once in the view's constructor and reuse it in onDraw.

Comment: Well, ok, but why the _top_ edge is visible then? :)

The point about Paint creation is taken, its just an artificial example.